# Cauchy's Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis

[image: photo of question]

Please can someone help me understand how to use the cauchy's integral formula? I have put a picture of a question which i am struggling to get the correct answer for! I have the formula but i am a bit confused as to how to use it as i keep getting the wrong answer!

Also, how will it benefit me using $z^2 +1 =(z+i)(z-i)$?

Answer (score 2):

If $f:U\to \mathbb{C}$ is an analytic function and $D$ is a closed disk contained in $U$ having $\gamma$ as its boundary, then Cauchy's integral formula says that $$f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} dz$$ for any $z_0 \in D$. So in order to solve your exercise, you need to somehow rewrite $1/(z^2+1)$ in this form. Hint: Try partial fractions decomposition on $1/(z^2+1)$ and then break the integral into two pieces both in the form of the Cauchy integral formula. Then all you have to do is determine what $f$ is for each integral and plug in the corresponding $z_0 = -i,i$.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for awhile when I was first learning complex analysis, and I would like to add something which is a bigger hint than given by Suugaku.  Let's rewrite our integral in the form $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} dz$:

$$\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{1+z^2} dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{\frac{2\pi i}{z+i}}{z-i} dz$$

Now apply the residue theorem.

Comment: Thank you! but what is the residue theorem? Im not sure it is part of my course! is there anyway of just doing the integral forumula twice?

Comment: edna1974, the reason I deleted a comment I previously wrote is because it also led you to use the residue theorem and then I realized you probably haven't learned it yet. The residue theorem makes everything easier :) But in this case you really don't need it and indeed you can split the integral to two. Suugaku wrote in his answer "partial fractions decomposition". Look at "Example 1" here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction I think this will answer everything :)

Comment: @edna1974: There is more than one way to do this integral, and my solution does use Cauchy's integral formula.  I figured you weren't allowed to use it, but I went with a hyper literal interpretation of your question.  What your teacher meant was ONLY using the Cauchy Integral formula and NOT the residue theorem :)  I could try explaining the residue theorem in 250 characters or less, but that would be a disaster.  If you skip ahead in your textbook, there should be an explanation.